# MongoDb Aggregation - Splitting into time buckets

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, time-series, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to use the MongoDB aggregation framework to generate a time series output where any source documents that are deemed to fall within each bucket are added to that bucket?

Say my collection looks something like this:

```js
/*light_1 on from 10AM to 1PM*/
{
    "_id" : "light_1",
    "on" : ISODate("2015-01-01T10:00:00Z"),
    "off" : ISODate("2015-01-01T13:00:00Z"),

},
/*light_2 on from 11AM to 7PM*/
{
    "_id" : "light_2",
    "on" : ISODate("2015-01-01T11:00:00Z"),
    "off" : ISODate("2015-01-01T19:00:00Z")
}
```

..and I am using a 6 hour bucket interval to generate a report for 2015-01-01. I wish my result to look something like:

```js
    {
        "start"         : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "end"           : ISODate("2015-01-01T06:00:00Z"),
        "lights"        : []
    },
    {
        "start"         : ISODate("2015-01-01T06:00:00Z"),
        "end"           : ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z"),
        "lights_on"     : ["light_1", "light_2"]
    },
    {
        "start"         : ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z"),
        "end"           : ISODate("2015-01-01T18:00:00Z"),
        "lights_on"     : ["light_1", "light_2"]
    },
    {
        "start"         : ISODate("2015-01-01T18:00:00Z"),
        "end"           : ISODate("2015-01-02T00:00:00Z"),
        "lights_on"     : ["light_2"]
    }
```

a light is considered to be 'on' during a range if its 'on' value < the bucket 'end' AND its 'off' value >= the bucket 'start'

I know I can use $group and the aggregation date operators to group by a either start or end time, but in that case, it's a one-to-one mapping. Here, a single source document may make it into several time buckets if it spans several buckets.

The report range and interval span are not known until run-time.

Comment: "a light is considered to be 'on' during a range if its 'on' value >= the bucket 'start', and its 'off' value < the bucket 'end'". According to this, how can light_1 come in this :    {
        "start"         : ISODate("2015-01-01T06:00:00Z"),
        "end"           : ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z"),
        "lights_on"     : [light_1, light_2]
    }

Comment: light_1's "off" is ISODate("2015-01-01T13:00:00Z") which is not lesser than "end"           : ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z")

Comment: apologies - I've amended the description above to correct this. Basically, a light is on if there is overlap between the bucket and the light's timespan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Introduction

Your goal here demands a bit of thinking about the considerations for when to record the events as you have them structured into the given time period aggregations. The obvious point being that one single document as you have them represented can actually represent events to be reported in "multiple" time periods in the end aggregated result.

This turns out on analysis to be a problem that is outside of the scope of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) due to the time periods that to are looking for. Certain events need to be "generated" outside of what can be just grouped on, which you should be able to see.

In order to do this "generataion", you need [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/). This has the "flow control" via JavaScript as it's processing language to be able to essentially determine whether the time betweeen on/off crosses more than one period and therefore emit the data that it occurred in more than one of those periods.

As a side note, the "light" is probably not best suited to the `_id` since it can possibly be turned on/off many times in a given day. So the "instance" of on/off is likely better. However I am just following your example here, so to tranpose this then just replace the reference to `_id` within the mapper code with whatever actual field represents the light's identifier.

But onto the code:

```js
// start date and next date for query ( should be external to main code )
var oneHour = ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ),
    sixHours = ( oneHour * 6 ),
    oneDay = ( oneHour * 24 ),
    today = new Date("2015-01-01"),               // your input
    tomorrow = new Date( today.valueOf() + oneDay ),
    yesterday = new Date( today.valueOf() - sixHours ),
    nextday = new Date( tomorrow.valueOf() + sixHours);

// main logic
db.collection.mapReduce(
    // mapper to emit data
    function() {
        // Constants and round date to hour
        var oneHour = ( 1000 * 60 * 60 )
            sixHours = ( oneHour * 6 )
            startPeriod = new Date( this.on.valueOf() 
              - ( this.on.valueOf() % oneHour )),
            endPeriod = new Date( this.off.valueOf()
              - ( this.off.valueOf() % oneHour ));

        // Hour to 6 hour period and convert to UTC timestamp
        startPeriod = startPeriod.setUTCHours( 
            Math.floor( startPeriod.getUTCHours() / 6) * 6 );
        endPeriod = endPeriod.setUTCHours( 
            Math.floor( endPeriod.getUTCHours() / 6) * 6 );

        // Init empty reults for each period only on first document processed
        if ( counter == 0 ) {
            for ( var x = startDay.valueOf(); x < endDay.valueOf(); x+= sixHours ) {
                emit(
                    { start: new Date(x), end: new Date(x + sixHours) },
                    { lights_on: [] }
                );
            }
        }

        // Emit for every period until turned off only within the day
        for ( var x = startPeriod; x <= endPeriod; x+= sixHours ) {
           if ( ( x >= startDay ) && ( x < endDay ) ) {
               emit(
                   { start: new Date(x), end: new Date(x + sixHours)  },
                   { lights_on: [this._id] }
               );
           }
        }
        counter++;
    },

    // reducer to keep all lights in one array per period
    function(key,values) {
        var result = { lights_on: [] };
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            value.lights_on.forEach(function(light){
                if ( result.lights_on.indexOf(light) == -1 )
                    result.lights_on.push(light);
            });
        });
        result.lights_on.sort();
        return result;
    },

    // options and query
    { 
        "out": { "inline": 1 },
        "query": {
            "on": { "$gte": yesterday, "$lt": tomorrow }, 
            "$or": [
                { "off": { "$gte:"  today, "$lt": nextday } },
                { "off": null },
                { "off": { "$exists": false } }
            ]
        },
        "scope": { 
            "startDay": today,
            "endDay": tomorrow,
            "counter": 0
        }
    }
)
```

### Map and Reduce

In essence, the "mapper" function looks at the current record, rounds each on/off time to hours and then works out the start hour of which six hour period the event occurred in.

With those new date values a loop is initiated to take the starting "on" time and emit an event for the current "light" being turned on during that period, within a single element array as explained later. Each loop increments the start period by six hours until the end "light off" time is reached.

These appear in the reducer function, which requires the same expected input that it will return, so hence the array of lights turned on in the period within the value object. It processes the emitted data under the same key as a list of these value objects.

First iterate the list of values to reduce, then looking at the inner array of lights, which could have come from a previous reduce pass, and processing each of those into a singular result array of unique lights. Simply done by looking for the current light value within the result array and pushing to that array where it does not exist.

Note the "previous pass", as if you are not familiar with how mapReduce works, then you should understand that the reducer function itself emits a result that might not have been achived by processing "all" of the possible values for the "key" in a single pass. It can and often does only process a "sub-set" of the emitted data for a key, and therefore will take a "reduced" result as input in just the same way as the data is emitted from the mapper.

That point of design is why both the mapper and reducer need to output the data with the same structure, as the reducer itself can also get it's input from data that has been previously reduced. This is how mapReduce deals with large data sets emitting a large number of the same key values. It processes typically in "chunks" and not all at once.

The end reduction comes down to the list of lights turned on during the period with each period start and end as the emitted key. Like this:

```js
    {
        "_id": {
            "start": ISODate("2015-01-01T06:00:00Z"),
            "end": ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            "result": {
                "lights_on": [ "light_1", "light_2" ]
            }
        }
    },
```

That "_id", "result" structure is just a property of how all mapReduce output comes out, but the desired values are all there.

### Query

Now there is also a note on the query selection here which needs to take into account that a light could already be "on" via its collection entry at a date before the start of the current day. The same is true that it can be turned "off" after the current date being reported on as well, and may in fact either have a `null` value or no "off" key in the document depending on how your data is being stored and what day is actually being observed.

That logic creates some required calculation from the start of the day to be reported on and consider the six hour period both before and after that date with query conditions as listed:

```js
        {
            "on": { "$gte": yesterday, "$lt": tomorrow }, 
            "$or": [
                { "off": { "$gte:"  today, "$lt": nextday } },
                { "off": null },
                { "off": { "$exists": false } }
            ]
        }
```

The basic selectors there use the range operators of [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) to find the values that are greater than or equal to and less than respectively on the fields that they are testing the values of in order to find the data within a suitable range.

Within the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition, the various possibilities for the "off" value are considered. Either being that it falls within the range criteria, or either has a `null` value or possibly no key present in the document at all via the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator. It depends on how you actually represent "off" where a light has not yet been turned off as to the requirements of those conditions within `$or`, but these would be the reasonable assumptions.

Like all MongoDB queries, all conditions are implicity an "AND" conditon unless stated otherwise.

That is still somewhat flawed depending on how long a light is possibly expected to be turned on for. But the variables are all intentionally listed externally for adjustment to your needs, with consideration to the expected duration to fetch either before or after the date to be reported on.

### Creating Empty Time Series

The other note here is that the data itself is likely not to have any events that show a light turned on within a given time period. For that reason, there is a simple method embedded in the mapper function that looks to see if we are on the first iteration of results.

On that first time only, a set of the possible period keys is emitted that includes an empty array for the lights turned on in each period. This allows the reporting to also show those periods where no light was on at all as this is inserted into the data sent to the reducer and output.

You may vary on this approach, as it is still dependant on there being some data that meets the query criteria in order to output anything. So to cater for a truly "blank day" where no data is recorded or meets the criteria, then it might be better to create an external hash table of the keys all showing an empty result for the lights. Then to just "merge" the result of the mapReduce operation into those pre-existing keys to produce the report.

### Summary

There are a number of calculations here on the dates, and being unaware of the actual end language implementation I am just declaring anything that works externally to the actual mapReduce operation seperately. So anything that looks like duplication here is done to that intent, making that part of the logic language independant. Most programming languages support the capabilities to manipulate the dates as per the methods used.

The inputs that are then all language specific are passed in as the options block shown as the last argument to the mapReduce method here. Notably there is the query with it's paramterized values that are all calculated from the date to be reported on. Then there is the "scope", which is a way to pass in values that can be used by the functions within the mapReduce operation.

With those things considered, the JavaScript code of the mapper and reducer remains unaltered, as that is what is expected by the method as input. Any variables to the process are fed by both the scope and query results in order to get the outcome without changing that code.

It is mainly therefore that because the duration of a "light being on" can span over different periods to be reported on, that this becomes something the aggregation framework is not designed to do. It cannot perform the "looping" and "emission of data" that is required to get to the result, and therefore why we use mapReduce for this task instead.

That said, great question. I don't know if you considered the concepts of how to acheive the results here already, but at least now there is a guide for someone approaching a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative response! You are correct of course that the light name is not a good ID for a light measurement metric. The actual problem I'm working on has a far more complex data structure, and I was simplifying this by hand.

Comment: @DavidBlack Not a probllem. I went to sleep when this was half written and did not notice the other anwer until submitted. As I commented there, the process given was mostly correct, but there are notable differences in this listing that you should be aware of when writing your end code. Mostly in the selection and in the reducer operation, for which the other answer gives incorrectly and would fail on you if you coded it that way.

Comment: I actually have 100 of millions of records like this to process - and there are other group stages and filters as well to work in, so am concerned about performance. The aggregation framework was doing a great job of computing non time-series metrics (e.g. top N lights of a certain type ordered by total time on etc.)

Comment: @DavidBlack But it cannot do this problem for the reasons as stated. Your data shows a "light on" that could possibly span multiple "buckets" you want to report on. The aggregation framework is great, but it cannot do that. As I said, read it through and at least take away the points that differ from the answer you accepted before, as with 100's of millions you do not want it to fail.

Comment: Very good example of mapReduce framework in action. I re-used it to count simultaneous calls per second in CDR database. One point is that I had to add `.valueOf()` to all datetime expressions in second emit cycle like `for ( var x = startPeriod.valueOf(); x <= endPeriod.valueOf(); x+= sixHours )` and `if ( ( x >= startDay.valueOf() ) && ( x < endDay.valueOf() ) )` to make it work correctly on Mongo 3.0.12

Answer (score 2):

I originally misunderstood your question.  Assuming I understand what you need now, this looks more like a job for map-reduce.  I am not sure how you are determining the range or the interval span, so I will make these constants, you can modify that section of code properly.  You could do something like this:

```
var mapReduceObj = {};

mapReduceObj.map = function() {
    var start = new Date("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z").getTime(),
    end = new Date("2015-01-02T00:00:00Z").getTime(),
    interval = 21600000;                     //6 hours in milliseconds

    var time = start;
    while(time < end) {
        var endtime = time + interval;
        if(this.on < endtime && this.off >= time) {
            emit({start : new Date(time), end : new Date(endtime)}, [this._id]);
            break;
        }

        time = endtime;
    }
};

mapReduceObj.reduce = function(times, light_ids) {
    var lightsArr = {lights : []};

    for(var i = 0; i < light_ids.length; i++) {
        lightsArr.lights.push(light_ids[i]);
    }

    return lightsArr;
};
```

The result will have the following form:

```
results :    {
    _id     :    {
        start   :   ISODate("2015-01-01T06:00:00Z"),
        end     :   ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z")
    },
    value   :    {
        lights  :    [
            "light_6",
            "light_7"
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

### ~~~Original Answer~~~

This should give you the exact format that you want.

```
db.lights.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$and": [ 
            { on  : { $lt : ISODate("2015-01-01T06:00:00Z") } },
            { off : { $gte: ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z") } }
        ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
        _id         :   null,
        "lights_on" : {$push : "$_id"}
    }},
    { "$project": {
        _id     :    false,
        start   :    { $add : ISODate("2015-01-01T06:00:00Z") },
        end     :    { $add : ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z") },
        lights_on:   true
    }}
]);
```

First, the `$match` condition finds all documents that meet your time constraints.  Then `$group` pushes the _id field (in this case, `light_n` where n is an integer) into the `lights_on` field.  Either `$addToSet` or `$push` could be used since the `_id` field is unique, but if you were using a field that could have duplicates you would need to decide if duplicates in the array were acceptable.  Finally, use `$project` to get the exact format you want.

Comment: Thanks c1moor and Aswin Jose Roy. Both approaches would work, but I was hoping to somehow include the splitting over intervals inside the aggregation rather than looping. I may have thousands of intervals to compute and it felt that doing it inside the aggregation might be better? I'll try with the loop approach and see how it goes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you given a list of intervals and you need to group the lights based on this list?  What is the format of the list of intervals you are passing in (e.g. is it an array of objects with fields `start` and `end`?

Comment: @DavidBlack Let me know if the updated answer helps you.

Comment: yes, I've tried this, and it works perfectly - many thanks! I had been struggling to see a use for MapReduce over Aggregation, and this shows a good example of why you might use it instead.

Comment: @DavidBlack Actually for you both. This is "close" but still not quite 100% correct. The looping is there which is the main thing, but what is missing is the correct "rounding" of date values and also the consideration for the date selection for lights that can be turned on/off before and after the reporting period. Also the reduce function is a little off and would fail on anything more that a small set of input. However I still think this deserves reward for effort and therefore gets a vote for useful from me.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to to use the [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator of $project and compare each "start" and "end" with the "on" and "off" fields in the original collection. Loop over each bucket using your MongoDB client and do something like this:

```
db.lights.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
       "present": { "$cond": [
           { "$and": [ 
               { "$lte": [ "$on", ISODate("2015-01-01T06:00:00Z") ] },
               { "$gte": [ "$off", ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z") ] }
           ]},
           1, 
       0
       ]}
   }}
]);
```

The result should look something like this:

```
{ "_id" : "light_1", "present" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "light_2", "present" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "light_3", "present" : 1 }
```

For all documents with `{"present":1}`, add the `"_id"` of lights collection to the `"lights_on"` field with your client. Hope this helps.